# database error no such table django

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I have made a new app 'api' in the django project 'cc'.

I have a remote database 'launchg' which I integrated it with Django using Legacies and used `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py` to generate a `models.py` file.

Next replaced the generated models.py file with the models.py file in the `api` app.

Whenever I try to fire a query into this Database `database error:no such table`
For Eg :- `WebQuery.objects.all()`, it throws an error stating `database error: no such table : web_query`

Here is my models.py file

```
    # This is an auto-generated Django model module.
    # You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
    #     * Rearrange models' order  
    #     * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
    # Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
    #
    # Also note: You'll have to insert the output of 'django-admin.py sqlcustom [appname]'
    # into your database.
    from __future__ import unicode_literals

    from django.db import models  

    class Area(models.Model):
        area_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
        area_name = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'area'

    class Business2(models.Model):
        business_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
        b_name = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
        b_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
        b_add = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
        area_id = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
        categories = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
        rating = models.IntegerField()
        latitude = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
        longitude = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'business2'

    class BusinessReply(models.Model):
        msg_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
        conversation_id = models.BigIntegerField()
        business_id = models.BigIntegerField()
        query_id = models.BigIntegerField()
        username = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
        message = models.CharField(max_length=500L)
        date_time = models.DateTimeField()
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'business_reply'

    class Businessnew(models.Model):
        business_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
        b_name = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
        b_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
        b_add = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
        area_id = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
        categories = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
        rating = models.IntegerField()
        latitude = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
        longitude = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
        home_delivery = models.IntegerField(db_column='Home Delivery') # Field name made     lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
        credit_card_facility = models.IntegerField(db_column='Credit Card facility') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
        menu_available = models.IntegerField(db_column='Menu Available') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    bar_available = models.IntegerField(db_column='Bar Available') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
        dine_in = models.IntegerField(db_column='Dine In') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
        pure_vegetarian = models.IntegerField(db_column='Pure Vegetarian') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
        cost = models.CharField(max_length=255L, db_column='Cost') # Field name made lowercase.
        timings = models.CharField(max_length=255L, db_column='Timings') # Field name made lowercase.
        check = models.IntegerField()
        url = models.CharField(max_length=500L)
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'businessnew'

     class BusinessnewBackup(models.Model):
         business_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
         b_name = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    b_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    b_add = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
    area_id = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
    home_delivery = models.IntegerField(db_column='Home Delivery') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    credit_card_facility = models.IntegerField(db_column='Credit Card facility') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    menu_available = models.IntegerField(db_column='Menu Available') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    bar_available = models.IntegerField(db_column='Bar Available') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    dine_in = models.IntegerField(db_column='Dine In') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    pure_vegetarian = models.IntegerField(db_column='Pure Vegetarian') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    cost = models.CharField(max_length=255L, db_column='Cost') # Field name made lowercase.
    timings = models.CharField(max_length=255L, db_column='Timings') # Field name made lowercase.
    check = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'businessnew_backup'

class BusinessnewBackup1(models.Model):
    business_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    b_name = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    b_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    b_add = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
    area_id = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
    home_delivery = models.IntegerField(db_column='Home Delivery') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    credit_card_facility = models.IntegerField(db_column='Credit Card facility') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    menu_available = models.IntegerField(db_column='Menu Available') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    bar_available = models.IntegerField(db_column='Bar Available') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    dine_in = models.IntegerField(db_column='Dine In') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    pure_vegetarian = models.IntegerField(db_column='Pure Vegetarian') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    cost = models.CharField(max_length=255L, db_column='Cost') # Field name made lowercase.
    timings = models.CharField(max_length=255L, db_column='Timings') # Field name made lowercase.
    check = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'businessnew_backup1'

class BusinessnewBackup2(models.Model):
    business_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    b_name = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    b_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    b_add = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
    area_id = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
    home_delivery = models.IntegerField(db_column='Home Delivery') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    credit_card_facility = models.IntegerField(db_column='Credit Card facility') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    menu_available = models.IntegerField(db_column='Menu Available') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    bar_available = models.IntegerField(db_column='Bar Available') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    dine_in = models.IntegerField(db_column='Dine In') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    pure_vegetarian = models.IntegerField(db_column='Pure Vegetarian') # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    cost = models.CharField(max_length=255L, db_column='Cost') # Field name made lowercase.
    timings = models.CharField(max_length=255L, db_column='Timings') # Field name made lowercase.
    check = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'businessnew_backup2'

class Businessowners(models.Model):
    b_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    b_id = models.IntegerField()
    userid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='UserID') # Field name made lowercase.
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100L)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100L)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=150L)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32L, db_column='Password') # Field name made lowercase.
    b_name = models.CharField(max_length=100L)
    b_address = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'businessowners'

class Categories(models.Model):
    cat = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
    syn = models.CharField(max_length=100L)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'categories'

class CiSessions(models.Model):
    session_id = models.CharField(max_length=40L, primary_key=True)
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=45L)
    user_agent = models.CharField(max_length=120L)
    last_activity = models.IntegerField()
    user_data = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ci_sessions'

class Query(models.Model):
    query_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    conversation_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    gcm_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    what = models.CharField(max_length=20L)
    where = models.CharField(max_length=500L)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200L)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'query'

class QueryBusiness(models.Model):
    business_id = models.CharField(max_length=10L)
    query_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'query_business'

class TzMembers(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    usr = models.CharField(max_length=32L, unique=True)
    pass_field = models.CharField(max_length=32L, db_column='pass') # Field renamed because it was a Python reserved word.
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
    regip = models.CharField(max_length=15L, db_column='regIP') # Field name made lowercase.
    dt = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tz_members'

class Users(models.Model):
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20L)
    fb_token = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    fb_likes = models.TextField()
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    gmail = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    gcm_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    last_login = models.DateTimeField()
    last_push = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'

class WebQuery(models.Model):
    query_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    conversation_id = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    u_id = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    u_query = models.CharField(max_length=500L)
    sent_to = models.CharField(max_length=500L)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    is_reply = models.IntegerField()
    is_responded = models.IntegerField()
    from_gingr = models.IntegerField()
    diff = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'web_query'

class WebReply(models.Model):
    reply_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    query_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    conversation_id = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    b_id = models.CharField(max_length=20L)
    u_query = models.CharField(max_length=500L)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=20L)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    diff = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'web_reply'

class WebUsers(models.Model):
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20L)
    fb_token = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    fb_likes = models.TextField()
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    gmail = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    gcm_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000L)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    last_login = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'web_users'
```

Moreover, when I typed the command `manage.py sql api` , it shows all the tables. What is it???

Kindly help!!!

Comment: Hi, this Database error has been solved.
Now when I fire a query `Users.objects.all()` it shows an empty list, although the data is present in the db.
any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is that firing `manage.py sql myapphere` will show the queries used to create the schema for your database, while the ouput of `myapp.objects.all()` will simply return a list of the entries in that database.

For example, if you had a list of articles, the manage.py sql command would show the myapp *properties* while myapp.objects.all() will show the *instances of myapp* in the database.

To further extrapolate your problem, try opening up your DB client and make sure the column names match the ones described in your model. If they don't match up, you might need to drop the table and resync your database (I definitely had that problem).